# AJAX call not picking up id and sending it to php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that I accept or deny new users. When someone is accepted they go to a section called Accepted Users and in that section the admin has to change their permission level or group#. So in the following I am getting the user_id from the user_request table for that specific user and wanting to update my users table by the id. I am only wanting to update the 'group' by the option box through an AJAX call to my php file.

For some reason the id and group # are not being found by my AJAX call and not sending to my php file.

In the headers part of the console I get the following after trying to send this..

id:0
update_group:

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
$con2 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$run2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT * FROM user_requests ORDER BY id DESC");
$runUsers2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($run2);

    if( $numrows2 ) {
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run2)){
            if($row2['status'] == "Approved"){

                $approved_id        = $row2['user_id'];
                $approved_firstname = $row2['firstname'];
                $approved_lastname  = $row2['lastname'];
                $approved_username  = $row2['username'];

    if ($approved_firstname == true) {
        echo "Name - ". $approved_firstname . " " . $approved_lastname . "</br>" . 
            "Username - ". $approved_username . "</br></br>"
?>
<div class="change_group_button"> 
     <a class="change_group" href="javascript:void(0)">Change User Permission</a>
</div><br>
<div id="light" class="change_group_popup">
    <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>

    <form id="update_group" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
       <div class="field">
        <label for="group">Group</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_id; ?>" id="approved_id" name="id" />
        <select id='group_id' name='group' required>
            <option value=''><?php echo htmlentities($group); ?></option>
            <option value="1">Bench</option>
            <option value="2">Spectator</option>
            <option value="3">Team Member</option>
            <option value="4">Commissioner</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#update_group').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'user_group_update.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            id: $("#approved_id").val(), //id
            update_group: $("#group_id").val() //group level
        },
            success: function (data) {
                //do something with the data that got returned
                $("#success").fadeIn();
                $("#success").show();
                $('#success').html('User Permission Level Changed!');
                $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                alert(data);
            },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown )
            {
              // alert on an http error 
              alert( textStatus +  errorThrown );
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

user_group_update file...

```
$approved_id = $_POST['id'];
$change_group = $_POST['update_group'];

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE users SET `group`=? WHERE id=?");
    if ( !$stmt || $con->error ) {
     // Check Errors for prepare
        die('User Group update prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->bind_param('ii', $change_group, $approved_id)) {
    // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('User Group update bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('User Group update execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
```

UPDATE:
SHOWING FULL CODE FOR HTML PART

```
if( $numrows2 ) {
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run2)){
            if($row2['status'] == "Approved"){

                $approved_id        = $row2['user_id'];
                $approved_firstname = $row2['firstname'];
                $approved_lastname  = $row2['lastname'];
                $approved_username  = $row2['username'];

    if ($approved_firstname == true) {
        echo "Name - ". $approved_firstname . " " . $approved_lastname . "</br>" . 
            "Username - ". $approved_username . "</br></br>"
?>
<div class="change_group_button"> 
     <a class="change_group" href="javascript:void(0)">Change User Permission</a>
</div><br>
<div id="light" class="change_group_popup">
    <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>

    <form id="update_group" action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
       <div class="field">
        <label for="group">Group</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_id; ?>" id="approved_id" name="id" />
        <select id='group_id' name='group' required>
            <option value=''><?php echo htmlentities($group); ?></option>
            <option value="1">Bench</option>
            <option value="2">Spectator</option>
            <option value="3">Team Member</option>
            <option value="4">Commissioner</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <p>Bench = 1</p>
    <p>Spectator = 2</p>
    <p>Team Member = 3</p>
    <p>Commissioner = 4</p>
</div>
<div id="fade" class="lighter_black_overlay"></div>
<?php               
                            ;} else {
                        echo "There are no Approved Users at this time.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you view the source of the page, in your browser, does the right value for `$approved_id` appear in your `<input type="hidden"...`?

Comment: No, it shows 0 when checking

Comment: In the first snippet you posted, you never close your `while` and your `if` statements (missing `}`'s). Is that the case in your actual code?

Comment: Yes. It has the closing brackets. I just added more of my html code into my question to show it.

Comment: into your while/if(approuve).. try to `var_dump($row2)`. and see what you get

Comment: Here's some of it.... `array(10) { ["id"]=> string(2) "14" ["user_id"]=> string(1) "0" ["firstname"]=> string(6) "george" ["lastname"]=> string(4) "bush`

Comment: you got it!... your user_id = 0

Comment: That isn't the correct user_id though.

Comment: check your database. because... you got all.. and only user_id not work properly... also... when an `"id"` is a `string`?

Comment: Then, that means that the user_id was not properly inserted in the database in the first place :/ Take a look at it, using PHPMyAdmin, for example.

Comment: Wait sorry, I was wrong. That was the correct user id.. That record was an old one that didn't have one. I used a current one and it sent to my db, but it is not picking up my 'group' value. It inserted a 0 into the db instead of a 3 like I chose.

Comment: ok but I give you a HINT.  where you setup your `$group` and... how you put `selected` param into your select option ?

Comment: have you an column into your request table linked with your user table?

Comment: Also, try narrowing down your problem as mush as you can by commenting any code unrelated to your issue. By the way, I'm surprised user "George Bush" got approved on your site, though... ;)

Comment: I gave the select box the id of `<select id='group_id'` and I am calling for that in my ajax call and then retrieving it in my php file, so why should the $group variable matter?

Comment: Well my user and user_request table both have the column group, but I had not added the logic yet to update the user_request table as of yet.. partially because I'm just learning how to do multiple queries...but for now I am just trying to update the users table as that is the table that matters for the most.

Comment: Excuse me but i don't understand , if form you  submit is printed 1 time or more? because problem could be two input hidden with the same id. If more than one you have to rename : approved_id_0 approved_id_1, and in javascript call them with the correct id.

Comment: Also for  <select id='group_id' . If in your html there are many input or select with the same id attribute javascript can't read the correct value

Comment: How would I change the id then per selected value? Just give each option a value?

Comment: @LucaOlivieri: he have the same bug with the "form id"... and he submit correctly. :-/ thats weird you know

Comment: So how could I correct this? Making more forms? How could I get that to work with the AJAX?

Comment: if the problem is this try :   $(this).find("#approved_id").val() to retrieve value of id. And for select $(this).find( "#group_id option:selected" ).val();

Comment: @Becky  Very good ! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write clearly what i wrote before in comments:
you have to specify that you want to read input values of the form you submit, because in your html there are many form,input and select with the same ids and that isn't good. So change :

```
  id: $("#approved_id").val(), //id
        update_group: $("#group_id").val() //group level
```

whith

```
    id:  $(this).find("#approved_id").val(), //id
    update_group: $(this).find( "#group_id option:selected" ).val()  //group level
```

Answer (score 2):

You have many issues here.. First of all.. you don't run this part:

```
$runUsers2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
```

so you don't have your `group` column

Now, you can merge your SQL like that:

```
$run2 = mysqli_query($con2,"SELECT user_requests.*,users.group FROM user_requests INNER JOIN users ON user_requests.user_id=users.id ORDER USERS BY id DESC");
```

Just to know that I dont know what is the configuration of your table so I guess that is ok.

Now, you need to get the groupe of your element like that:

```
$group= $row2['group'];
```

and now, if you want to select you may use something like:

```
    <?php $selectedstring = "selected"; ?>
    <select id='group_id' name='group' required>
        <option value=''><?php echo htmlentities($group); ?></option>
        <option <?php echo $goup=='1'?$selectedstring:''; ?> value="1">Bench</option>
        <option <?php echo $goup=='2'?$selectedstring:''; ?> value="2">Spectator</option>
        <option <?php echo $goup=='3'?$selectedstring:''; ?> value="3">Team Member</option>
        <option <?php echo $goup=='4'?$selectedstring:''; ?> value="4">Commissioner</option>
    </select>
```

Also, into your submit ajax, use something like:

```
     $.ajax({
        url: 'user_group_update.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
        'id': $("#approved_id").val(), 
        'update_group': $("#group_id").val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //do something with the data that got returned
            $("#success").fadeIn();
            $("#success").show();
            $('#success').html('User Permission Level Changed!');
            $('#success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
            alert(data);
        },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown )
        {
          // alert on an http error 
          alert( textStatus +  errorThrown );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, I don't really need to know the current group level that the user is because they will always be 1 when they have registered. I make the value of one for all people who register which doesn't allow them to access the site or login until granted a higher permission.

Comment: I don't see what was changed in the AJAX. So you are thinking if I convert the option values to php that would help? Sorry for the bad questions.

Comment: if you don't need that, why you run SQL, try to push non-declared variable into your screen? I make add quote in the first part of your Ajax. will not be fix your problem but could help. Also, in this page.. you displayy more than 1 user or just 1?

Comment: Because I'm thinking about adding it. I wanted to finish all of this once I am at least sending this initial part.